# Airbrush and Soft Pencil always black, regardless of material chosen (2D, 2.8)

Tags: materials, 2d

When using 2D animation in 2.8, my airbrush and soft pencil tool always produce the color black, regardless of material chosen.  The other drawing tools are accurate. and draw/paint what I've selected.  Any idea what I may be doing wrong, or missing?  Thanks so much.

Answer (score 1):

I've figured it out. Airbrush and Soft Pencil are Dots material. If you have only Line materials, blender will switch to the default "Dots Stroke" material, which is black. Change the color of this material.

[image]